# Can I generate new keystore password and key password or change the existing for signing android applications?

Tags: android

Can I generate new keystore password and key password or change the existing for signing android applications?

I have created keystore password etc earlier with this command

```
C:\>keytool -genkey -v -keystore release.keysore -alias Android -keyalg RSA -key
size 2048 -validity 10000.
```

Now If I'm trying to create a new one

But it is showing errors.

Comment: You misspelt _keysore_ instead of _keystore_. You're not giving the shown error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting or removing the keystore file you crteated from the directory you are trying to create a file in.

Comment: also, looks like you are misspelling "release.keysore". Should be release.keystore

Comment: any command for deleting it automatically. Iam not  finding it .earlier I have created  it in C drive.